# Select many rows by unique columns with good performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select

I want to select about 20 to 100 rows from a table using four columns which make up an unique index.

The first approach I came up with was using `OR`:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE (w_id = ? AND type_id = ? AND object_id = ? AND part_name = ?)
   OR (w_id = ? AND type_id = ? AND object_id = ? AND part_name = ?)
   OR [...]
```

I've also seen a solution using row constructors:

```
SELECT ...
WHERE (w_id, type_id, object_id, part_name) IN ((1,2,3,''),(1,2,4,''), [...])
```

However, it was said that this has a bad performance when selecting many rows.

Which solution has the better performance or should I use an other solution (such as splitting  the queries)?

Thanks in advance!

**Table structure**

```
CREATE TABLE page(
    page_id PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    w_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    ns_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    type_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    object_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    part_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
);
```

Both `w_id` and `ns_id` are foreign keys.

There is only one index, which is the unique index containing the columns `w_id`, `type_id`, `object_id` and `part_name`.

**Measurement**

I filled the table with about 700k rows and ran three querys (also one with using `UNION`). I always queried for the same rows. These are the results:

```
Solution  Time [s]  EXPLAIN
with OR   0.0003    ref
with IN   0.4546    ALL
UNION     0.0004    const
```

Raymond's presumption that using an `IN` could cause a full table scan was proved. However, the results show that `OR` and `UNION` show quite the same time.

What also makes me worry is the fact that these results only were achieved after a defragmentation. Before the defragmentation even the solution with `OR` took about 0.3 s.

Comment: Try the two solutions on your data and report back which is faster.

Comment: We also could use the table structure and information about indexes and used storage engine, number off records in what table, example data in sqlfriddle would also be nice.   the IN clause could force an full table scan in MySQL

Comment: @GordonLinoff I made the test

Comment: `Both w_id and ns_id are foreign keys.` is `{w_id,ns_id}` a candidate key? And: are `{type_id, object_id, part_name}` by any chance functionally dependent on (a combination of) any of the other `xxx_id` fields?

Comment: @wildplasser `{w_id, ns_id}` is not a candidate key and there is no functional depention of `{type_id, object_id, part_name}`. However, `w_id` funtionally depend on `ns_id`.

Comment: @JimmyT. . . . Interesting result.  The `union` and `or` are doing basically the same thing -- using the index to look up particular values (if you are using `union` instead of `union all` there is additional overhead for duplicate elimination).

Comment: @GordonLinoff I tested it with `union all` but it's also 0.0004 s

Comment: So, you _do_ have a normalisation problem. Get rid of it. BTW: what is the cardinality of `w_id` compared to  `ns_id` ?

Comment: @wildplasser The relation between `w_id` and `ns_id` is 1:n. I've put `w_id` into the table to make queries faster because otherwise there would be no unique index. Furthermore, the `w_id` never changes.

Comment: @JimmyT. : given the functional dependancy, the 1:N is obvious. At first, I thought you had a BCNF or 4NF violation; but now it appears to be even a 3NF violation. [Just for the sake of performance: since w_id is dependent on ns_id, not only the w_id field is redundant, but also any indices you need to create on it. (and its cardinality will always be <= the cardinality of ns_id) ] Famous last words: the need for UNION and/or AND/OR clauses are often the result of a sub-optimal data model.

Comment: @wildplasser I know that this is a violation of 3NF but if I would create a completly redundance-free data model the many joins would have a bad influence on the performance. Is it really so bad if I do so?

And I don't know how I could create a redundance-free, optimal and performant data model but maybe I can eliminate the need of UNION and/or AND/OR clauses.

Comment: Another way to write this type of query is to load the (20) rows in a (regular or temporary or memory) table, add (or not) an index on it and `JOIN`.

Comment: @ypercube What are the benefits of this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting using `=`, `AND` and `OR`/`UNION ALL` works faster than using `IN` in combination with row constructor. `IN` forces a full table scan which makes it a few times slower than the other solution.

However, on the recommendation of wildplasser:

> "the need for UNION and/or AND/OR clauses are often the result of a sub-optimal data model"

I will change my data base model so there is no need for selecting the rows in this way but rather I'll use a join.